# shouldAutorotate in subclassed UINavigationController is returning NO but rotation still occurs

Tags: ios, ios7, rotation, orientation

I have a view controller which I want to lock down in portrait mode. By creating a custom navigation controller I have been able to force portrait mode when the device is in landscape, and that works initially when the app starts up.

But when I rotate the device to portrait mode and then back to landscape, the orientation changes again.

I would assume that shouldAutorotate returning NO should prevent this, but it doesn't for some reason. I verified that function is being called every time I physically rotate the device.

Anyone know why iOS is ignoring my shouldAutotate of NO?

I've read many posts on this and my code seems to be what many people are suggesting, but doesn't work.

```
@interface MyUINavigationController : UINavigationController

@end

@implementation MyUINavigationController

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait ; 
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
     NSLog(@"shouldAutorotate called and returning NO");
     return NO;
}

@end

// This is how I am using my custom Navigation Controller:

UINavigationController* mynav = [[MyUINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:customViewController];
visibleVC = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
[mynav setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen]; 
[mynav setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve]; 

[visibleVC presentViewController:mynav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Check if my answer on this post helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18335720/382834

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help because I want to lock the orientation even if the device is rotated.